# How do I data bind select lists to arrays in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to have two drop down lists that contain integers 1 to 9 each initially. I think I can do that using something like the following:

```
<--html area-->
<select ng-repeat="num in MaxCupcakes">
    <option ng-model="num" />
</select> 

<select ng-repeat="num in MyCupcakes">
     <option ng-model="num" />
</select> 

<--script area -->

var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function() {

   $scope.MaxCupcakes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
   $scope.MyCupcakes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 

});
```

Once I get this setup correct I would like what ever is selected in MaxCupcakes to limit the number in MyCupcakes. For example, if I set max cupcakes to 5, then I can only select 1-5 in mycupcakes.

Comment: `ng-repeat` would be used on `<option>` but more common to use `ng-options` on `<select>`

Comment: there's a lot going wrong with this code. you have arrays with a single malformed object in them, injecting something isn't used ($filter), ngRepeating the wrong elements, every option has a value of 1, ngModel on option rather than select and using the same value for both. I realize (hope) this is pseudo code, so you might want to spend some time creating something closer to working and then ask for help when you get stuck.

Comment: MrObrian, it is from working code that I am trying to shorten and sanitize. I do admit that I am struggling with learning angular, so please allow some room for not having it perfect when asking for help. It would be a high bar to have everything right in order to ask a question. I was shooting more for general idea so someone could say use ng-really-cool-array-binding-thing instead of expecting a working copy of what I am trying to do. Thanks for your input, regardless and I will fix the incorrect parts of my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better method would be to use a filter on the second select.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="max">
        <option ng-repeat="num in MaxCupcakes" ng-click="changeMax(num)">
            {{num}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="foo>
        <option ng-repeat="num in MyCupcakes | limitTo:max">
            {{num}}
        </li>
    </select>
</div>
```

Also your arrays shouldn't have the {}.  Here's what the ctrl should look like.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.MaxCupcakes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
    $scope.MyCupcakes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    $scope.max = 9;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this is more than I was expecting and is a great example of how to do what I was looking for. I didn't think about filters.